# Passing and take props with screen option in DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using `DrawerNavigation` and I have `Notifications` Page

which i can use multiple time but with different props.

```
const MyApp = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: MyHomeScreen,
    },
    Notifications: {
        screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
    },
});
```

I found answer screen:

````
(props) => <MyNotificationsScreen {...props} propName={val1} />``` but I can't receive data.Can you help me?
````

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the parameters between drawers navigators,

Pass the required data to the `screenProps`. I don't know what kind of bug the **function** I'm using now, but I haven't seen it while I'm using it.

```js
const SomeStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  // config
});
<SomeStack
  screenProps={/* this prop will get passed to the screen components as this.props.screenProps */}
/>
```

**Example**

```js
const SomeStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  // config
});
...
class MainScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: "somedata"};
  }

  render() {
    return(<SomeStack screenProps={{ data: this.state.data}} />
  }
}
```

// Now you can do in your screens

```
console.log(this.props.screenProps.data);
```

Comment: Sorry ,but I need give data to each screen not to whole navigation,or i need to add screenProps everywhere?

Comment: Yes, you should use this method to deliver to the screen you want. You'd better use a global variable if you had to deliver data to all screens.